# Determine the orthogonal projection of $L^2$ onto $\left\{f\in L^2:\int f=0\right\}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, orthogonality

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a probability space and $$L^2_0(\mu):=\left\{f\in L^2(\mu):\int f\:{\rm d}\mu=0\right\}.$$ It's easy to see that if $c\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, then $$c\perp_{L^2(\mu)}f\Leftrightarrow\langle c,f\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}=0\Leftrightarrow\int f\:{\rm d}\mu=0\Leftrightarrow f\in L^2_0(\mu)\tag1$$ for all $f\in L^2(\mu)$ and hence $$\{c\}^\perp=L^2_0(\mu).\tag2$$

> Now let $\pi_0$ denote the orthogonal projection from $L^2(\mu)$ onto $L^2_0(\mu)$. I'm confused by the following: $\operatorname{id}_{L^2(\mu)}-\pi_0$ should be the orthogonal projection from $L^2(\mu)$ onto ${L^2_0(\mu)}^\perp=\{c\}^{\perp\perp}=\overline{\{c\}}=\{c\}$, but this seems to be strange since $c$ was arbitrary. What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't the orthogonal projection from $L^2$ to $L^2_0$ just be $X \mapsto X-E[X]$? Also the orthogonal complement of $L^2_0$ would be all the constant random variables, not just one particular constant.

Comment: @Ian But $\{c\}^\perp=L^2_0(\mu)$, do you agree? Then we should have $\{c\}=\{c\}^{\perp\perp}=L^2_0(\mu)$, since $\{c\}$ is closed.

Comment: The double orthogonal complement is the closed linear span, not the closure.

Comment: @Ian Sure, you're right. So, formally, ${L^2_0(\mu)}^\perp={\{c\}}^\perp=\overline{\langle c\rangle}=\mathbb R$, where $\langle c\rangle$ denotes the linear span of $\{c\}$, right?

Comment: Well, no, it's all the random variables which are equal to some constant a.s. But that can be reasonably identified with $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Ian I was implicitly using that $\mathbb R$ is isometrically embedded into $L^2(\mu)$. BTW, could you take a look at my similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3323770/47771?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)
For $\pi_0$, observe that
\begin{align*}
f=c_f+(f-c_f),
\end{align*}
where $c_f=\int_{\Omega} f d\mu$ is the average of $f$ (assuming $\mu(\Omega)=1$).

To claim $\pi_0(f)=f-c_f$, we have to check that $f-c_f\in L^2_0(\mu)$ and 
\begin{align*} f-c_f\perp c_f, \end{align*}
which are left to you.

(2)
$(M^{\perp})^{\perp}=\bar{M}$ only works when $M$ is a vector space. For example, in $\mathbb{R^2}$, 
\begin{align*}
((1,1)^{\perp})^{\perp}=\{(x,y)|x-y=0\}\neq\{(1,1)\}.
\end{align*}