# The spectrum of an irreducible reversible Markov kernel is contained in $[-1,1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, operator-theory, spectral-theory, markov-process

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space, $\kappa$ be a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$, $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$ reversible with respect to $\kappa$ and $$L^2_0(\mu):=\left\{f\in L^2(\mu):\mu f=0\right\}.$$ We may treat $\kappa$ as a self-adjoint linear contraction on $L^2(\mu)$ via $$\kappa f:=\int\kappa(\;\cdot\;,{\rm d}y)f(y)\;\;\;\text{for }f\in L^2(\mu).$$ By contractivity, the spectrum $\sigma(\kappa)$ of $\kappa$ is contained in $[-1,1]$.

> Let $\kappa_0:=\left.\kappa\right|_{L^2_0(\mu)}$. In the last paragraph on page 9 of [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.3606&rep=rep1&type=pdf), it is claimed that if $\kappa$ is irreducible, then $\sigma(\kappa_0)\subseteq[-1,1)$. How can we prove that?

I could imagine that the guideline of the proof is as follows:

1. Show that $\mathcal N(1-\kappa)=L^2_0(\mu)$ (compare with the result of [Determine the orthogonal projection of $L^2$ onto $\left\{f\in L^2:\int f=0\right\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3324075/47771))
2. From [If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a self-adjoint operator, is $\lambda$ in the resolvent set of $\left.A\right|_{{\mathcal N(\lambda-A)}^\perp}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3376495/47771) we can conclude t that $1-\kappa_0$ is injective and hence $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $\kappa_0$
3. We somehow need to conclude (probably using the irreducibility) by Theorem 12.29-c in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*:
   [image: Rudin, Theorem 12.29-c]

How can we fill the gaps?

Comment: Can you remark on what irreducible means for the operator $\kappa_{0}$? I'm not familiar with probability theory.

Comment: @s.harp Take a look at Proposition 2.1 in https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ecp/1453832497. The only relevant thing should be what's mentioned in Remark 2.1: The irreducibility implies that the spectral radius of $\kappa_0-U$ is less than $1$, where $$U:L_0^2(\mu)\to L_0^2(\mu)\;,\;\;\;f\mapsto \mu f:=\int f\:{\rm d}\mu.$$

Comment: You mean $\kappa-U$, right and $U:L^2(\mu)\to L^2(\mu)$, not $L_0^2(\mu)\to L_0^2(\mu)$, as $\ker(U)=L_0^2(\mu)$, correct? If my interpretations are all true, you can get that the spectral radius of $\kappa_0=\kappa_0-U\lvert_{L_0^2}$ has spectral radius $<1$, in particular $\sigma(\kappa_0)\subsetneq (-1,1)$.

Comment: @s.harp Actually, whether $\kappa$ is considered as an operator on $L^2(\mu)$ or $L^2_0(\mu)$ is exactly the point which confuses me as well. It's clear that $\sigma(\kappa)\subseteq[-1,1]$ (simply by contractivity) and hence the same inclusion is true for the spectrum of $\kappa_0$. On the other hand, $1-\kappa_0$ is injective (hence $1$ is not an eigenvalue) which is *not* true for $1-\kappa$. Now in Remark 2.2 the authors explicitly use the symbol $\left.P\right|_{\pi^\perp}$, which is our $\kappa_0$, and thereafter $r(P)$ (but it seems like they mean $r(\left.P\right|_{\pi^\perp})$.

Comment: @s.harp Moreover, they stress the fact that we need to restrict the operator to $L^2_0(\mu)$ in order to obtain that $1$ is not in the spectrum. But since their notation is not consistent, I'm highly confused. (BTW, is $U$ compact?)